# Unable to determine gdb version in eclipse using PTP and SDM on OSX

Tags: eclipse, gdb, debugging

I had this working fine until today and I have seemingly tried everything. I get an error when I try to launch a debugger in eclipse with PTP on OSX. The error comes up as:

> Error completing debug job launch 
>   Reason:  Debugger error: Unable to
>   determine gdb version

I have tried running the same code in regular debugger, minus all the MPI stuff and that works fine. It also works fine when I simply run the MPI job locally. I have read somewhere that this might be an issue with Process Launcher? Where do I check this in PTP? I am also using latest Indigo eclipse with PTP version 5.0 and I have also built the sdm ddebugger for mac locally.

This also appears in console:

```
gdb: invalid option -- q
sdm [--debugger=value] [--debugger_path=path]
    [--proxy=proxy]
    [--ho
st=host_name] [--port=port]
     [--master]
    [--server=rank]
    [--debug[=level]]
```

Finally, running gdb from terminal gives me:

> GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version
>   gdb-1515) (Sat Jan 15 08:33:48 UTC
>   2011)

Any ideas?

Thanks, Alex